# Left Navigation Margin

Tags: navigation

I am building a SharePoint site in 2013.  I have used CSS Code to remove the Quick Launch in the left navigation panel.   I then added a table.  However, my table is still indented beyond where the quick launch would have ended.  I need to know how to shift that margin to use the blank space. Any help is greatly appreciated!!
Example:

Quick Launch Removed - Table still starts way over here even though quick launch has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The quick launch table name is **table. ms-nav** so, you can try with **display:none**  or reducing the height and width, almost to 0 px.

Example:

```
type="text/css">
table.ms-nav { width: 1px ; }
</style>
```